# How to use an ImageVector in a Glance widget?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, glance-appwidget

I want to use an `ImageVector` from `androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended` in a Glance widget. As far as I know, the only possibility to add an image to a Glance widget is using `androidx.glance.image` , with an `ImageProvider`, which only accepts `Int`, `Icon` or `Bitmap` as argument.

I have tried to convert the `ImageVector` into a `Bipmap` with no success. My current code is as follows:

```
Image(
        provider = ImageProvider(
            //ImageVector goes here
        ),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = GlanceModifier.padding(top = 4.dp).size(40.dp),
     )
```

Comment: any luck on this?

Comment: no, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [Vector Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio) to import your icons as resources and then your can use ImageProvider to draw the imported resource.

Comment: I could do so, but I'd like to use directly the icons in the ExtendedIcons library without creating more XML